# prebuilt jupyterlab extension in jupyterhub

Tags: docker, dockerfile, jupyter-lab

I am working on a JupyterHub, where we have JupyterLab 3 interface. I want to install a [prebuilt jupyterlab extension](https://github.com/educational-technology-collective/etc-jupyterlab-cell-iterate-run). I only can adapt the profile via a dockerfile. I am not sure how to adapt [this](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_dev.html#distributing-a-prebuilt-extension) into a docker command.